# Call srand outside main and before variable declaration

Tags: c++, class, object, random

I need to use rand() on my program but the thing is that it is called on a class and the objects I create need to be in the global scope so I need to call srand() before the main and on the global scope is there a way?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include "Electron.h"

srand(time(0));
Electron el1;
Electron el2;
Electron el3;
Electron el;


int main(int argc, char** argv){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ensure that`srand` has been called a single time before any call of `rand`, regardless of in which translation unit, you can do this:

```
auto my_rand()
    -> int
{
    static bool const dummy = (srand( time( 0 ) ), true);
    return rand();
}
```

Here `dummy` will be initialized exactly once, in the first call of `my_rand`.

So just use `my_rand` instead of using `rand` directly.

---

In other news:

- Global variables are Evil™.
  They introduce invisible lines of data flow and influence, making it hard to understand what's going on in a program.
- C++11 introduced better random generators than `rand`.
  However, they're more complex. I can't even name them out of my head here, I'd have to look them up. But I think you'll find it's worth it, if you're doing a simulation.
- `time` is an ungood source of entropy.
  A high resolution clock from `<chrono>` would be far better. Otherwise you risk the same seed for runs that start at roughly the same time (within a second).

Comment: Thanks, but I can't call my_rand on the Electron class or am I wrong?

Comment: You don't call it *on* that class. That is not a meaningful phrase. You call it from that class' code.

Answer (score 4):

Globally-scoped objects declared in the same translation units will be constructed in the order they are declared. So, you could declare a stub class, and have its constructor call `srand`().

```
class invoke_srand {
public:
     invoke_srand()
     {
         srand(time(0));
     }
};

static invoke_srand do_invoke_srand;

Electron el1;
Electron el2;
Electron el3;
Electron el;
```

However the order of construction of globally-scoped objects in different translation units is unspecified, so you're only guaranteed that, in this case, `srand()` will be invoked before the globally-scoped in this translation unit get constructed, and you have no guarantees about the construction order of globally-scoped objects in other translation units.

Comment: You don't need to define a class for this (it would be another matter if cleanup was required). Just e.g. `bool const dummy = (srand(time(0)), true);`.

Comment: Well, you do waste a byte of precious RAM this way. True, RAM's much cheaper than it's used to be, but I hate to see precious bytes go to waste.

Comment: There's no waste, that's a misconception of yours. So, the class is a **premature optimization**. And worse, it's a premature optimization that doesn't solve a problem, because the imagined problem doesn't exist.